# How to use symfony routing with vuejs?

Tags: javascript, symfony, vuejs2

I am new with VueJS and I want to use it with my Symfony plateform.
I am wondering how I can add a VueJs Variable inside a twig variable.

Here is my example :

```
<div v-for="competition in Vcompetitions">
     <div class="thumbnail">
       <a v-bind:href="XXX">
         <img v-bind:src="competition.src">
       </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Consider the desired twig path is: `{{ path('name', {'id' : THEID })}}`,and the VueJs variable is `competition.id`
I don't know what to do on **XXX**.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **FOSJsRoutingBundle**, check the doc :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/installation.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

Step 1: You can change vuejs delimiters `{{ }}` to `${ }`

```
           $(document).ready(function () {
                var app = new Vue({
                    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
                    el: '#app',
                    data: {
                        competition: {"id":1},
                    },
                });
            });
```

Step 2: Now you can use something like bellow in your twig file

 For vuejs variable `${competition.id}` and for twig variable `{{competition.id}}`. In your case `{{ path('name', {'id' : ${competition.id} })}}`

Comment: This doesnt work, Im getting Unexpected character "$" error. I did this <a href="{{ path('slug' , {'slug' : ${ competition.slug} })}}">

Comment: can you change delimiters `delimiters: ['${', '}'],` ?

Comment: Can you please show your `app.js` or main app js file

Comment: Sorry I dont have main app js File, I only the the JS code above.

Comment: I say about those file, where you initialize your vuejs code!

Comment: var competition = new Vue({
   delimiters: ['${', '}'],
   el: '#vuecompetition',
     data: {
       Vcompetitions: competitions,
     }
  });
That's It !